# How to have apps script loop through a range where the number of values can change

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a fairly basic sheet set up to produce monthly review forms for operatives across multiple working shifts, by reading performance data from a central file into a pre-formatted document depending on shift and name selected in dropdowns.

My intention is that once I have selected a shift, my script iterates through the dropdown of operative names and spits out a completed review sheet per operative.

I am most of the way there as best as I have been able to cobble together using the below script, which is running through the operative names, copying/pasting the whole sheet values-only into a temporary sheet to strip out formulae, then copying that temporary sheet across to a newly-made monthly file and renaming the duplicated sheet to the operative name.

The only issue I am having is that the named range for the operative names is set as *Ranges!B2:B151* in the base file, however the actual list of names may only be the first 20-30 cells, depending on the number of operatives on the selected shift. Therefore the script is failing when it hits the first blank value at the end of the list of names.

Could someone suggest a tweak to take into account the varying length of the dropdown list please. I'm sure I'm missing something fairly obvious to those more experienced. I have tried searching, however without knowing my terminology I can't see the wood for the trees.

```
function loopExport() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Report');
  var month = sheet.getRange('N6:Q6').getValue();
  var shift = sheet.getRange('B6:C6').getDisplayValue();
  var data = ss.getSheetByName('Ranges').getRange('Names').getValues();
  var ssnewname = "Operative Reviews - "+shift+" - "+month;
  var ssnew = SpreadsheetApp.create(ssnewname);
  var tempsheet = ss.getSheetByName('TempCopy');

  // Get dropdown values from named range Names
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // Assign dropdown values in Report
    sheet.getRange('E6:G6').setValue(data[i][0]);
    // For each name, copy & paste values-only into temp sheet
    sheet.getRange('A1:Q52').copyTo(tempsheet.getRange("A1"),{contentsOnly:true});
    var opname = tempsheet.getRange('E6:G6').getValue();
    // For each name, copy temp sheet to new workbook ssnew and set name to operative name
    tempsheet.copyTo(ssnew).setName(opname);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share a spreadsheet with some dummy data? In that way it will be easier to visualize the problem and then help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function loopExport() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName('Report');
  var month=sheet.getRange('N6:Q6').getValue();
  var shift=sheet.getRange('B6:C6').getDisplayValue();
  var data=ss.getRangeByName('Names').getValues();
  var ssnewname="Operative Reviews - "+shift+" - "+month;
  var ssnew=SpreadsheetApp.create(ssnewname);
  var tempsheet=ss.getSheetByName('TempCopy');
  for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][0]) {
      sheet.getRange('E6:G6').setValue(data[i][0]);
      sheet.getRange('A1:Q52').copyTo(tempsheet.getRange("A1"),{contentsOnly:true});
      var opname=tempsheet.getRange('E6:G6').getValue();
      tempsheet.copyTo(ssnew).setName(opname);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works beautifully for the loop and export, thanks so much for this. Unforeseen issue is that it loops and copies across that quickly that the vlookups don't refresh in time, so everyones data on the exported copy is for the person behind them on the list. How might I add a very short delay within the loop to account for recalcs?

Comment: Dummy link below. Have removed linked sheets and pasted generic values in the data source sheet (normally from an importrange). For similar reasons this dummy will only work with "Lates" selected as shift, as the names list won't repopulate when changing shift. Dummy sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_U2G9QAgsVjB3HT4OOSApoAae0fpzV_AA4NE_LFLz0c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Try using spreadsheet app flash in the loop it will slow everything down but it will force for spreadsheet to complete all the calculations and display it